# Running Vagrant Up error - 'Never run this as root (or with sudo).'

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Windows - Vagrant and VM Virtual Box

If I use Vagrant Up command, I get an error.
"Never run this as root (or with sudo)."

Vagrant file opens with this...

```
# prevent accidental sudo / root
if Process::uid == 0
  puts "Never run this as root (or with sudo)."
  exit 1
end
```

How do I run Vagrant Up and not get this error?

Comment: From the vagrant tag: **GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC.** Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you `sudo su` then type `exit` to get out of sudo.

Or if you always use root - create another user on your unix host.

Comment: 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows - Vagrant and VM Virtual Box